# Bake the AO to add Grunge

Tags: node-editor, baking

Trying to follow along with tutorial I've done everything EXACTLY as he decribes every step of the way --however at only 35 seconds in when I try to "Bake the AO" I get an error message "*No active UV layer found in the Object Suzanne*" --what didn't I do right?

http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-grunge/
[How to Grunge](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-grunge/)

Comment: You must first [UV unwrap](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/38651/599) the object. For the purposes of baking all you probably need to do is enter edit mode (`Tab`) and press `U`> *Smart UV Project* or *Lightmap pack*.

Comment: You'd think he could have put that in the tutorial huh? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A [UV map](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/38651/599) is required in order to [bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13508/599).

To UV unwrap a mesh, switch to *edit mode* (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>) and press <kbd>U</kbd>.
Usually an automated method like *Smart project* or *Lightmap pack* is good enough for baking, but for other uses you may want to use manually placed seams.

See

- [What does unwrapping a model do and why is it important?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/38651/599)
- [How to properly unwrap my mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6755/599)