# What does it mean when I click "Bake" and it says "no active UV layer found in object"?

Tags: node-editor, texture-baking, baking, uv-image-editor

[image: screenshot with the error message at the top]

I am UVmapping the plane and making a new image for the UV map. Afterwards I put it in the node. After I click Bake, it says "no active UV layer found". 
What I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bake the AO to add Grunge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41449/bake-the-ao-to-add-grunge)

Comment: Make sure you are in (object) mode before you start baking. I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a node made material into an image texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90096/how-can-i-convert-a-node-made-material-into-an-image-texture)

Comment: Probably Selected to Active in Bake settings is used with 2 objects selected where active one doesn't have UV map

Comment: You have to be in object mode to bake.

Comment: It is not required to be in Object mode to bake, [it works just fine in Edit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9rqz.gif), the OP likely has another problem

Answer (score 2):

Go to the node editor. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to add image texture. Select your image. (No need to connect the node)... now try to bake and it should work. I'm not on blender at the moment but off the top of my head I believe the steps should work....