# Add an image texture to a plane correctly

Tags: texturing

I have added some planes and i want to add image textures for them. But when I add textures it looks like this.

[image]

See textures are not applied correctly. Can some one please help me to get this done since I am new to blender.Sometimes it may be a small one but any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The planes aren't [UV unwrapped](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38651/what-does-unwrapping-a-model-do-and-why-is-it-important) and most likely use default texture coordinates. You could use genererated texture coordinates or unwrap the mesh and use UV mapping.