# Why can't I edit image for UV Map after joining Objects?

Tags: uv

I have 2 problems:

1. How do you use the same UV image for multiple objects? It looks like each of my objects have different UV Images.
2. Why can't I edit UV Images when I joined all my objects? I can't edit all UV Images via Texture Paint mode and only 1 UV image is showing for 1 object.

[image: UV Image problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UV unwrap the mesh and select the texture you want it to be mapped to

Split the screen, turn it into the UV Image Editor.

Go back to the 3D view editor, select all the faces in Edit mode by pressing<kbd>A</kbd>

And back in the UV Image Edit header, you can select the image you will use as the texture.

[image]

Here is a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QN7boOlRteA)

To texture paint it, you need to apply the texture. This is example is in Blender render, are you using cycles?
[image]

Comment: could you perhaps add instructions on how to do what you are suggesting?  As your answer is written now, someone may not be able to follow it.,

Comment: If you upload you .blend (and pack the textures into the file) I can make a gif of how to do it. Or you can read this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38651/what-does-unwrapping-a-model-do-and-why-is-it-important/38653#38653

Comment: Thanks. The unwrap idea was good. I selected all and pressed U to Unwrap and that made all the UV images in one image. But I still can't edit the new images. How do you select the texture to be mapped to?
Here's a link of a copy of the project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwfXGrgxI_SrcW5aSmhUOHFxc2c

Comment: Very nice GIF thanks!
But here's the problem I am getting:
http://i.giphy.com/l41YmPSMa2TThNWb6.gif

Comment: Are you able to draw on all objects using Texture Paint Mode?

Comment: yes, there are lots of tutorials on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7ALfRw6I5I

Comment: Looks like you need to flip the normals on the hat first though. Select everything in edit mode, Then press "recalculate" in the (t)toolshelf-->Shading/Uvs-->Normals-->recalculate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41062/discussion-between-akusan-and-eromod).