# What do UV seams do exactly?

Tags: uv, edit-mode

I'm still trying to work out my texture distortion issue and while looking through Blenders UV functions I found UV seams.

Can someone explain to me what UV seams do and what they can be used for?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/unwrapping/seams.html

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to save the marked seams for importing into other programs like 3ds max?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38651/what-does-unwrapping-a-model-do-and-why-is-it-important