# How can I color a Banana?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

Ok, so, as a complete beginner with Blender, I've been trying to create a banana.

Here is the basic model :

[image]

I ,then, applied a basic yellow color to the mesh :

[image]

And now I am trying to add some sort of gradient "yellow to green" effect on the extremities of the mesh (as shown in this reference photo) :

[image]

But I have no idea on how I can do that. I've tried to play with the node editor, using a *Gradient* texture node, followed by a *Color Ramp* node, but the best thing I could get was that :

[image]

As you can see, It is applying only to one side of the mesh, and It is not even rotated properly to fit the shape of the object.

Am I on the right way to solve the problem ? Or should I perhaps simply try to UV Unwrap and apply a texture to it ?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: The **best** way to do this is UV Unwrapping, but it is not required. You can do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick update of the final result (forgot to answer) :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK7mu.jpg

After struggling for hours trying to color it, and mainly having problems to rotate the color propagation on the mesh, I found that I definitly needed to UV Unwrap the mesh in order to apply a clean rotation (using the mapping node). So I did an UV project from View, and tried to give a straight vertical shape onto the UV. Here is what It looked like : [image]

Then, the rotation of the color applied correctly to the mesh. Here is the node setup : [image]

I don't know why tho, my "color stops" had to be stacked on the left side...

And finally, I applied a black material to the extremities of the banana...

But yeah, It worked after all ! Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 7):

Your approach is conceptually correct, you are only missing texture coordinates.

You can even skip the gradient texture and use raw UVs.

The most accurate method is to [unwrap you mesh and make a proper UV map](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38651/what-does-unwrapping-a-model-do-and-why-is-it-important/38653#38653), but if you want to skip it, since the banana is an elongated almost-linear shape you can approximate it by using basic *Generated* texture coordinates.

They won't be as accurate as a proper manual UV mapping, but may do a passable job with less work.

Just use a *Converter > Separate XYZ* node to get the Y component of your *Generated* texture coordinates, then run those through the color ramp.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this fast answer ! Problem solved ! I'll still try to do the second method you suggested (UV unwrap).

Answer (score 0):

Add >> Vector >> Normal
Plug it into your Gradient Texture *Vector*
Spin the ball icon around 'till everything lines up.

Comment: I tried it but It diffused the color ramp colors to the entirety of the model. All I need is to get both extremities of the model green... I might be doing something wrong... https://imgur.com/a/VqxUU