# texture to scale on object

Tags: texturing

I modelled an object in Siemens NX with dimensions 150x150x60mm and I want to apply a tile-able texture to it with dimensions 10x10mm. 
The size of the texture needs be the right scale, since I need to export the obj-file for my machine input.

I need a method that I can apply to shapes and textures with unknown scaling factors.

Answer (score 1):

Well exporting textures is [going to be an issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures) but I'll assume here you will only require exporting UV coordinates.

This would be trivial to accomplish using any type of automated texture coordinates like *Generated* or *Object*, however, to be able to export texture coordinates you will most likely be required to [unwrap your mesh and create a UV map](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38651/what-does-unwrapping-a-model-do-and-why-is-it-important?s=2%7C22.6908), unwrapping doesn't translate well into scene referred units, since unwrapping will more often than not introduce distortions.

The way I see it you have two options, both involving third party addons.

Either use [World Scale UV](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?275652-Addon-World-Scale-UV) or [Magic UV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S876GhnIddU) [addon](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?v=S876GhnIddU&event=video_description&redir_token=Vkvuv73WhtaXgpxWsZygKN0UI7J8MTUxODE5NjQyOUAxNTE4MTEwMDI5&q=http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.blender.org%2Findex.php%2FExtensions%3A2.6%2FPy%2FScripts%2FUV%2FCopy_Paste_UVs).

What they both do is try to unwrap your mesh in such way that it approximates texture size to a defined scene dimention.