# How to achieve the same function like 3dsmax?

Tags: texturing

*UVVMapping→ Box→ Length/Width/Height*, not Scale/Size.

[image: Length width height]

Thanks

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100373/texture-to-scale-on-object/100400#100400

Comment: Also, please use descriptive titles

Comment: sorry, my English is very bad.

Comment: Please explain clearly what that function does, or what you expect to find in blender.