# How Do I Add An Image Onto An Object?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, image

I'm trying to make a flag, and I read online that to add an image to something all you have to do is drag it from your computer onto the block, which I did. I then checked to see if the image rendered onto the block by checking the picture render and there is no image. Why is it not working?

[image]

[image]

Right now this is just a plane with an image on it.

Thanks

This is not blender cycles. This is blender render. So the case is different. You cannot drag an image from your pc onto the plane in blender cycles, whereas this is the method I used in blender render

EDIT: the object is a plane

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38651/what-does-unwrapping-a-model-do-and-why-is-it-important

Comment: Please use the built-in uploader when adding images to your post. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put an image texture on a material in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles)

Comment: It's not. This is blender render

Comment: To direct comments to specific users you need to '@' them, e.g. '@RayMairlot'. Otherwise they won't get notified of new comments.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos its not. this is blender render

Comment: Any reason you are using Blender Internal and not Cycles? You will get a lot more help if you use Cycles.