# UV unwrap and get same coordinates

Tags: uv

How can i uv unwrap but keep x and y coordinates of my vertices the same?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The transform coordinates are referred to the world coordinates, expressed in Blender Units, while the UV coordinates are expressed in pixels, with 0,0 left bottom corner, and 256 x 256 as default (size changes according to a selected image in the UV/Image window), so it doesn't make sense try to match the two values. If you want to mantain the shape use a square texture and select "project from view" as UV Unwrap algorithm.

A workaround can be using your texture as reference, create a "cage" with the dimensions of the texture, then inset the face you need, choose Unwrap "project from view (bounds), then delete the faces you don't need.

[image]

Comment: to do project from view, i have to adjust the view over and over, with is too slow.
or i can just copy and paste coordinates, but that is slow as well.
is there better way to do this?

Comment: @kaito why adjusting the view "over and over"? This is done once before unwrapping. Select face/-s, press Shift+Numpad 7 to align view to active face and press U > Project From View. This is one of unwrapping techniques, while there're a lot of others, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/38651/1245

Comment: @MrZak when i do that, vertice coordinates are not the same.
it also depends on how zoomed in your view is.

Comment: Maybe it's better if you explain us whta do you want to achieve, because the corrispondance you're asking for is not possible, as UV coordinates can't have negative values, while transform values can. So, probably, you can reach your goal with a different workflow.

Comment: here is what i am trying to do. i have texture 16x64 and have a face 80x64. when i unwrap that face, i want it to perfectly match that texture. that's why i want to get same xy coords in uv editor when unwraping. otherwise i have to scale and move that face in uv editor, with most of the time not matches the texture perfectly.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: @joshsanfelici thanks, but that's not it. if i'm gonna do that, i still have to move vertices. this is what i want to happen when i unwrap. https://i.imgur.com/YzzILKF.png

Comment: @MrZak I just wanted to say that this is seriously the last time I ever use a new shortcut without saving my work. Shift+Numpad 7 COMPLETELY screwed the viewport. I can't even realign this now. For anyone else who reads this, do NOT press Shift+Numpad 7.

Comment: @Krythic Shift+Numpad7 alignment can be easily undone by pressing Numpad1 to enter front view and then pressing MMB to exit it and continue working with perspective (if Auto Perspective enabled). There're also addons to store 3d views if needed. Avoiding using alignment to face just because it shifts viewport is avoiding multiple useful ways to work.