# Material that uses Texture Coordinates won't "stick" to meshes in a physics simulation

Tags: animation, materials, node-editor, shaders, soft-body

My material uses a Texture Coordinate node, so it won't stick to meshes that are part of a physics simulation. I assume this is because the node uses the mesh coordinates but not the delta transforms associated with the simulation.

In the attached blend file you can see how the material sticks to a mesh animated using location keyframes but does not stick to an identical soft body mesh influenced by a wind force. Does anyone know how I can get the material to stick to this mesh?

P.S. this is my first post and I'm new to Blender.

[image]

Comment: You have to [unwrap your mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38651)

Comment: Thanks, Duarte! This worked: (1) unwrap mesh––it took some tinkering to get the seams/projection right, and (2) change Texture Coordinate node output from Object to UV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duarte Farrajota Ramos really deserves credit for this, but the solution is as follows:

1. In the UV Editing workspace, select mesh in Object mode.
2. Switch to Edit mode and select all vertices in the mesh (A).
3. Press U to unwrap mesh. (If it has already been incorrectly unwrapped, delete the existing UVMap from the Object Data Properties, one of the tabs in the Properties Editor on the right).
4. Choose an unwrapping method from the menu. In this case, Cube Projection worked best.
5. Change Texture Coordinate node output from Object to UV.