# Help me with texturing a room (UV unwrapping/stretched textures)

Tags: modeling, rendering, materials

I've added some textures to my models and they keep looking stretched out no matter what I tried.

When I try to edit the models in other texture programs it still is the same. [image]

And it's like this for every part of my models.

Comment: Hello, please show your UVs in the UV Editor, the unwrap must be incorrect

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: Did you unwrap your model? I guess you didn't, try to select one of the faces of the mesh, hit U on your keyboard and select unwrap, you will see that it should go back to normal

Comment: please paste the file so I can take a look at it

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38651/what-does-unwrapping-a-model-do-and-why-is-it-important

Comment: @Ribbit12
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1esu0m006ofPZ2z24vKjluWcViBwr0saw/view?usp=sharing


Here is the file.you can text me on discord : IcyHot#2018

Comment: @yesmehello: if you want help, you should not make the helpers have to request for viewing for blend file...and by the way, the "official" side to provide blend file is this:https://blend-exchange.com/ because everybody can access it

Answer (score 3):

**Hi!
Please follow these steps to achieve this final result**

[image]

[image]

I just added a simple checker texture to the mesh so that we can see the UVs of the object(right now the UVs are terrible)

[image]

Now I went to the UV editor tab, selected all the faces of the object, pressed 'U' on the keyboard and selected the 'Cube projection' option. Then I selected all the UVs by pressing 'A' and scaled them by pressing 'S' to check out the final result.