# .Step file problem

Tags: texturing

I have an issue with .STEP file.

Blender doesn't show my image texture on a .STEP file imported from Solidworks.

I am working with shader editor and shading window and the wood material is missed

The strange thing: a mesh directly created into blender shows the material perfectly, while the object imported as .step file doesn't read any texture.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38651/what-does-unwrapping-a-model-do-and-why-is-it-important/38653#38653

Comment: Thank you so much!!